# Need help figuring out why this C pipe in a loop fails with more than two iterations

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to write a shell program in C and trying to implement a pipe in a for loop that takes the output from one unix command and uses it as input for the next. It works fine with only two commands, but whenever I try to use it with more than two, the program "hangs" and the processes never finish (aside from the first one). Here is the relevant code

```
  int fd[2];

  pipe(fd);

  for (l = 1; l <= pipeno; l++)
  {
    switch (pid = fork())
    {
      case 0:
        if (pipeno == 1)
        {
          close(fd[0]);
          close(fd[1]);
          dup2(indest, 0);
          dup2(outdest, 1);
        }
        else if (l == 1)
        {
          dup2(fd[1], 1);
          close(fd[0]);
          dup2(indest, 0);
        }
        else if (l == pipeno)
        {
          dup2(fd[0], 0);
          close(fd[1]);
          dup2(outdest, 1);
        }
        else
        {
          dup2(fd[0], 0);
          dup2(fd[1], 1);
        }
        execvp(args[l - 1], argStrings[l - 1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s failed my message\n", args[l - 1]);
        exit(1);
      case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  close(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);
  if (in == 1)
  {
    close(indest);
  }
  if (append != -1)
  {
    close(outdest);
  }
  while ((pid = wait((int*)0)) != -1)
  {
    printf("process %d finished\n", pid);
  }
```

"pipeno" is the number of commands to be chained together. "indest" and "outdest" are the fds of input and output files (or stdin and stdout). The close(indest) and close(outdest) at the end are meant to close opened files. I assume the problem lies in the final else branch but I'm not sure what it is

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have *one pipe*. How many pipes did you need in your *pipeline*

Comment: consider the command line, for each `|` character you need to create a **new** pipe.